# retrieving WordPress custom field values

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I have 2 custom fields in my post named Status and Version. I would like to retrieve the value of the field Status to display within the post. According to the documentation the following should retrieve the value.

```
<?php get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Status', true); ?>
```

However nothing is returned.

Doing the following

```
<?php the_meta(); ?>
```

Returns the names and values of all the custom fields, so they appear to be added correctly and working.
Am I doing something wrong, or does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say "nothing is returned", what are you expecting

```
<?php get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Status', true); ?>
```

to do? `get_post_meta` just returns the value, it doesn't echo it, and you're not storing it in a variable.  Does adding `echo`, like this:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Status', true); ?>
```

do what you're after?

Comment: Ahh of course, been working on this for too long today, making all the simple mistakes